# how to store a stream of values returned by console, swift 2.2

Tags: swift

How can I store each sample value (heartrate beats per minute) streamed from the console,  to store each 'value' of the 'values' and calculate the average in my next function.
Using NSUserDefaults is just storing the last  value.

```
 func updateHeartRate(samples: [HKSample]?) {
    guard var heartRateSamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {return}

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        var heartratePeak = 0.0
        guard let sample = heartRateSamples.first else{return}
        let values = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.heartRateUnit)
        self.label.setText(String(UInt16(value)))
        print(value)
            while true {
                if values > heartratePeak {
                    heartratePeak = values
                    print("heartrate Peak is")
                    print(heartratePeak)
                    continue
                }
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(values, forKey: "bpmValue")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(heartratePeak, forKey: "heartratePeak")

func average(values: Int...) -> Double {
    var sum = 0
    var count = 0
    for value in values {
        sum += number
    }
    var  ave : Double = Double(sum) / Double(count)
    return ave
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "streamed from the console"? You can't read any "console" in your code.

Comment: Also your code is missing so many closing curly braces that it is unclear how things are supposed to fit together.

Comment: thanks Matt, I am a beginner, not sure of the terminology. I am seeing the values returned in my console, am wanting to know how to store them. I am using NSUserDefault as I want to store the peak value for use in another function on a different controller. I would like to store the stream of heartbeats returned from the function so that I can graph this etc. and calculate the average.

Comment: "I am using NSUserDefault as I want to store the peak value for use in another function on a different controller" Okay, that can make sense, so let's not worry about that. But then that has nothing to do with storing the stream.

Comment: Also I can't make sense of your code. You say `print(value)` but there is nothing in your code called `value`. There is a different thing called `values` but where does this `value` even come from????

Comment: My question is how I can store the values other than NSUserDefaults as, (as I stated) the NSUserDefaults isn't a solution -that is the only way I know how to store values, so that is why I'm posting this question to ask how else I can store it. That is the question I"m asking.

Comment: I am wanting to find how to store the 'value' so that it can print the value. Sorry if this is not clear enough for you, and you can't make sense of my code, I will hope someone else can help me. I am a beginner, am doing my best.

Comment: excuse me?  am not picking a fight here, I'm just trying to solve a problem.  Yes I know it won't compile and that is why i'm asking a question. There is no need to critique code for not working when that is the point of asking a question. I was not saying it is your problem. You are saying you can't make sense of my code as if it is my problem -but that is why I have posted the question and tried to explain - give someone a chance. I said I am sorry if this is not clear enough for you> maybe it will be clearer to someone else.

Comment: I have made it clear that I'm a beginner. Everyone needs to start somewhere. I learned from you - thank you for that. I wasn't criticizing you - perhaps you are taking this personally. It is not mandatory to answer questions so please if you don't like my question as it doesn't make sense to you or isn't worded well enough for you then please leave it to someone else who would like to try. thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to make sense of your question, but I think the problem stems from your use of the term `values` in your code when this is in fact only one value! If you want to store each value as it arrives, use an array property:

```
var values = [Double]()
func updateHeartRate(samples: [HKSample]?) {
    // ...
    let value = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.heartRateUnit)
    self.values.append(value)
    // ...
```

Now you can go back at any time and fetch all the values stored in `self.values` (e.g., to average them, to find the max, or whatever).

Comment: Thank you Matt! yes am wanting to store each value as it arrives (wasn't sure how to phrase that).